# Is there any setting that causes F5 to do a full Rebuild Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010: a few months ago I think I was playing around with options in VS2010 and I think I checked some option that was saying whenever we want to compile, it should do a full rebuild ...now in my solution I have a lot of projects and it takes a lot of time to compile the project and I was thinking maybe that is the culprit. But today I couldn't find it. Do we even have such an option in VS2010 or I am thinning wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Tools` -> `Options`, under `Projects and Solutions` -> `Build and Run`, there is an option for what to do when the projects are out of date. Out-of-box, it set to `Prompt`, but you may have set it to `Always build`.